# Calling function from for loop - issue with parameters: NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, geopy

I am calculating commute distances (home to offices) for all employees. This works for a single office with this piece of code:

```
#Calculate distances from home to all other offices
def distances_to_offices(row):

    row['distance_to_office'] = round(distance.distance(row['Home_geocode'], row['Office_geocode']).km,0)
    return row

df_joined.apply(distances_to_offices, axis=1)
```

I have many offices though and would like to for loop through them, creating a new column for distances for each office.
The function is called without an argument but "row" is set as parameter in the function definition.
When i try to pass a city name, I need to call the function with the same number of arguments like in the function definition, yet that is not working out as "row" is not understood as argument:

```
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

I don´t understand why "row" works as argument in the function definition but not when I try to call it with that argument.
Who can help shedding some light?
I am thinking of something like this but struggle with chosing the right arguments:

```
# throws Name Error:
def distances_to_offices(row, city):
    col_name = city + "_distance"
    row[col_name] = round(distance.distance(row['Home_geocode'], row['Office_geocode']).km,0)
    return row

offices = ['NY', 'Rio', 'Tokyo']
for city in offices:
    df_joined.apply(distances_to_offices(row, city), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say for sure because I don't know what df_joined is, but it looks like it is some object representing a data table on which you can call `apply()` passing in a function, and `apply()` will loop through the table, calling the function you have supplied while passing in a row index or name for every row of the data table.

The first way you did it works because you are passing the NAME of the function `distances_to_offices` to apply(), and apply() is calling it with a `row` which gets defined in some for loop that it sets up.

The second way you did it fails because you are no longer passing the NAME of `distances_to_offices`, but instead CALLING it with arguments `row` and `city`, then passing the result of that function call as an argument to `apply()`. That can't work because you haven't defined what `row` is, but Python needs to know what `row` is in order to do the function call `distances_to_offices(row, city)`, which happens BEFORE apply sees it and has an opportunity to define `row`.

I'm not sure how df_joined.apply() works, so without more information I can't say the right way to do this. One strategy would be to create a new data table object in each iteration of the loop by filtering df_joined to retain only rows that have a city matching `city`.

Comment: I understood that calling a function is different to applying it. So I moved the for loop into the function to get to the desired outcome:

` def distances_to_offices(row):
    offices = ['NY', 'Rio', 'Tokyo']
    for city in offices:
        col_name = city + "_distance"
        row[col_name] = round(distance.distance(row['Home_geocode'], row[city]).km,0)
    return row

    
df_joined.apply(distances_to_offices, axis=1)` (Not sure why `` doesn´t turn it into code markdown)